tags after {children} being duplicated in react app
i have a layout
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <PageHeader />
        <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between pt-24">
          {children}
        </main>
        <PageFooter />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

and a page using that
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <RootLayout>
      <ImageCarousel />
      <About />
      <PortfolioSection />
      <TestimonialSection />
      <NewBlogSection />
      <ContactFormSection />
    </RootLayout>
  );

but when the page loads everything after the {children} is duplicated an there is the run time error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
which looking into doesn't seem to help all that much
regardless of what is passed as a child in as children into the rootlayout it happends

With Next.js, you don't need to import your RootLayout to your page, Layouts will be applied to whatever pages in the same directory and down the tree.

Oh that was it! I'm surprised I didn't see that anywhere else, or in any of the errors

@TheHarlequin because it's not really an error lol, but yeah kinda tricky
